# How to create paging with a menu at the top?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create something similar to the following:

[image: Screenshots of an app]

You see the dates at the top just underneath the search bar? Is that a nested tab view as I'm guessing? Is there a way to do it with the default components or do I need to create a custom view?

I'm not looking for a coding answer per se. I just want to know if there's a standard way of achieving this before trying to implement my own solution.

**EDIT:**
For future reference I found [a library](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController) that does exactly this.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this. Very commonly, use a customized `UISegmentedControl` for your "dates" and navigate between views when a segment is selected - or, change the selected segment if you are implementing "swipe between views." I suggest searching for `uisegmentedcontrol switch views` to get started with your research.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for the pointer! I'll give that approach a go then.

Comment: The Question that you asked for is not a Question it is all a new Project, Yes it is Possible to make does TabView, but need to work on it, there is no question about it, it is more challenge Goal

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation states :

*The tab bar interface displays tabs at the bottom of the window for selecting between the different modes and for displaying the views for that mode. This class is generally used as-is, but may also be subclassed.*

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

So I would guess that it is a custom solution.